# Is there any way to get data as Response in View side after delayed job complete in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to import one CSV file, i give that task to DelayedJob to perform, that DelayedJob call one method which read CSV and put data in one object, now what should i do to get that object as response in View side. Is there any way to tackle this?

Note: After assigning job to DelayJob my main action is completed with 200(Success).

Comment: Yes, either through polling (repeated ajax requests) or by using ActionCable (websockets) which allows duplex communication. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: If you need output of the CSV parsing available to the requester immediately, perhaps you shouldn't be using a delayed job in the first place. Just have the controller action do the parsing as you don't need asynchronous processing. Otherwise as others have said you would need to poll for either changes or processing completeness from the view or controller and show them as new changes become available or the processing completes.